# AsyncDataPublisher reconnection failed

Tags: wso2-esb

I am trying simple proxy service, which takes request at TCP port and does 2 or 3 mediation tasks and send the data to db. That's all.. It is all working fine.. Though something is not right here.. I am getting following logs at console, could someone help me understand what is going wrong here and how can I get rid of this. 
    Service doesn't send anything back to the client, is there any way to say that or it is implicit with the flow. Appreciate help.

```
[2015-11-12 10:57:13,550] ERROR - AsyncDataPublisher Malformed url error when connecting to receiver
java.net.MalformedURLException: The url protocol is not tcp or ssl
        at org.wso2.carbon.databridge.agent.thrift.internal.utils.AgentServerURL.<init>(AgentServerURL.java:53)
        at org.wso2.carbon.databridge.agent.thrift.DataPublisher.<init>(DataPublisher.java:152)
        at org.wso2.carbon.databridge.agent.thrift.DataPublisher.<init>(DataPublisher.java:88)
        at org.wso2.carbon.databridge.agent.thrift.AsyncDataPublisher$ReceiverConnectionWorker.run(AsyncDataPublisher.java:789)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
[2015-11-12 10:57:13,565] ERROR - AsyncDataPublisher Reconnection failed for
[2015-11-12 10:57:13,581] ERROR - AsyncDataPublisher Reconnection failed for
[2015-11-12 10:57:18,593] ERROR - AsyncDataPublisher Reconnection failed for
[2015-11-12 10:57:23,582] ERROR - AsyncDataPublisher Reconnection failed for
[2015-11-12 10:58:53,737] ERROR - AsyncDataPublisher Reconnection failed for
[2015-11-12 10:59:03,746] ERROR - AsyncDataPublisher Reconnection failed for
```